# Reading from a file in by specifying start point and end point

Tags: c#, streamreader

I want to read from an input file in C#. Below is my code.

```
public string ReadFromNewEntityFile()
    {
        string template=null;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        //char[] sourcesystemhost=null;
        string inputFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputNewEntityFilePath"].ToString();
        System.IO.StreamReader myFile;
        try
        {
            myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFileName);
            myFile.ReadLine();
            while ((template = myFile.ReadLine()) != "[[END SourceSystemHost]]")
            {
                s.AppendLine(template);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("In Filehandler class :" + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("Input file not read" + ex.Message);
        }
        return template;
    }
```

The problem is want to specify the starting point and end point for reading the contents. Here I am able to specify only the end point. How can i specify the starting point?

Please help

Comment: is the start point specified in bytes, lines, or characters? or via a sentinel string? it matters a lot

Comment: @MarcGravell Wow.. very nice. I was about to just post a `Seek` example.. I really have to get better at asking for clarifications like that.

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Depending on how much you need to do with the file and how big it is wouldn't it also suffice to just go `string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);` and then handle the contents of the file?

Comment: Start point is a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your start/end "points" are actually lines, you basically need to read from the start and skip the lines until you reach the right one. Here's an easy way of doing it using [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(inputFileName)
                .SkipWhile(line => line != "[[START SourceSystemHost]]")
                .Skip(1) // Skip the intro line
                .TakeWhile(line => line != "[[END SourceSystemHost]]");
```

Comment: Readlines is not an identified method for System.IO.StreamReader

Comment: I had to use System.IO

Comment: @user2124167: Or use `System.IO.File.ReadLines`, of course - but it's generally a good idea to have `using` directives for every namespace you're using in a file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `File.ReadLines` which does the same but more readable. Then use LINQ to find your start- and end-points:

```
var range = File.ReadLines(inputFileName)
   .SkipWhile(l => !l.TrimStart().StartsWith("[[Start SourceSystemHost]]"))
   .TakeWhile(l => !l.TrimStart().StartsWith("[[END SourceSystemHost]]"));

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, range);
```